# Is there a way to dynamically select all multi-select values on a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

[image: I'm trying to select all the available Offices below]

I'm trying to automatically select all available offices below..

Comment: To mark them as selected on a VF page

Comment: The multiselect picklist value I'm working with is on the standard ContentVersion object and not on a VF page. How can I automatically select all values using apex?

Answer (score 1):

If office is a salesforce multiselect pick list and not a custom one you built, you can follow below steps,

1) Call an action function/action support when checkbox is selected

2) In the action function in controller assign all values to the field(remember that the values will be separated by ;)

3) Rerender the field in page from action function. If it is not rerendering properly, you may have to rerender the entire page block section or wrap the field in an output panel and rerender that.

Comment: The multiselect picklist value I'm working with is on the standard ContentVersion object and not on a VF page. How can I automatically select all values using apex?